# what design tips would you give any designer to make the website popular and memorable amongst its users?

Tags: website-design

When designing a website that is targetting large number of consummers, what design tips would you give any designer to make the website popular and memorable amongst its users?

Answer (score 1):

- Design and Style(look and feel)
- Ease of Use, Simplicity
- Easy to find what you're looking for
- Easy Navigation
- Performance
- Being Dynamic
- Innovation

Answer (score 1):

- Focus on making it *simple* and *clear* for users to do what you want them to do on the website.
- Fun would be an added bonus.
- Avoid a registration process like the plague

Answer (score 0):

*Content* is what makes a website popular and memorable, not the design.

If you want the *design* to be "memorable", then just create an original and distinctive design. It's not hard to make a design that stands out (e.g. use loud colors, an animated background, and an annoying audio loop). What's hard is making a *good* design that stands out. That's a talent that great designers get paid a lot of money for having. As there's no magic formula that works every time, you're not likely to find a list of tips that can help you achieve this objective.

However, there are lots of tips that can help you *not* create a *bad* design. And if you follow those rules, you'll at the very least not end up with a hideous and unpopular design. Or better yet, learn the basic principles of design, and you'll be able to extrapolate the rules yourself (or they'll just come intuitively after a while).

Start with:

- color theory
- composition

  - balance
  - white space/negative space
  - proportions
- typography
- information architecture

  - proximity/grouping
  - visual hierarchy
- alignment/consistency
- repetition
- contrast
- brand/identity

**Edit:**
This is something that designers spend their entire careers cultivating (as with most skills, it all boils down to practice & dedication), but these 2 articles are a good crash course on avoiding poor typography:

- [“What Font Should I Use?”: Five Principles for Choosing and Using Typefaces](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/12/14/what-font-should-i-use-five-principles-for-choosing-and-using-typefaces/)
- [Best Practices of Combining Typefaces](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/04/best-practices-of-combining-typefaces/)